# Issue with Writing to File in x64 Assembly using MASM on Windows

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, writefile, createfile

I'm trying to write to a file using x64 assembly with MASM on Windows, but the content is not being written correctly. I've included my code below, but I'm not sure where the issue is. I'm using the CreateFileA and WriteFile functions. Can someone please help me identify and fix the problem?

Assembler: MASM
Architecture: x64
Platform: Windows

Code snippet:

```
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib
ExitProcess PROTO
CreateFileA PROTO
WriteFile PROTO

clearRegisters MACRO
    XOR RAX, RAX
    XOR RDX, RDX
    XOR RCX, RCX
    XOR R8, R8
    XOR R9, R9
ENDM

GENERIC_WRITE    EQU 04000000h   ;Solution 040000000h
FILE_SHARE_READ  EQU 1
FILE_SHARE_WRITE EQU 2
OPEN_ALWAYS      EQU 4
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL EQU 128

.DATA
    filePath BYTE "D:/thanks/ASSEMBLY.txt", 0
    fileHandle QWORD ?
    txt BYTE "Learning Assembly for shellcode development.", 0
    num DWORD ?

.CODE
main PROC
    clearRegisters
    SUB RSP, 64
    
    LEA RCX, filePath
    MOV RDX, GENERIC_WRITE
    MOV R8, FILE_SHARE_READ OR FILE_SHARE_WRITE
    MOV R9, 0

    MOV QWORD PTR [RSP+32], OPEN_ALWAYS
    MOV QWORD PTR [RSP+40], FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
    MOV QWORD PTR [RSP+48], 0

    CALL CreateFileA
    MOV fileHandle, RAX

    clearRegisters
    MOV RCX, fileHandle
    LEA RDX, txt
    MOV R8, LENGTHOF txt
    LEA R9, num
    MOV QWORD   PTR [   RSP+32  ],  0



    CALL WriteFile
    TEST RAX, RAX


    CALL ExitProcess
main ENDP

END
```

i have implement correctly agruments of CreateFileA and Writefile but after wirtefile call, rax content zero(0) which indicate it's fail.

Comment: It should be `sub rsp,56` and then a file with the contents is created.

Comment: i change sub rsp, 64 to sub rsp, 56 but still face same issue.

Comment: Program didn't create file because I didn't have `thanks` directory on drive D:. I created it manually. What about `CreateDirectoryA`? First create a path and then a file.

Comment: I have this Directory  D:/thanks so i think path is not problem.

Comment: because ASSEMBLY.txt is created but with empty contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my computer.

I added `CreateDirectoryA`.

`GENERIC_WRITE` was `04000000h` in Your code and should be `40000000h`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/generic-access-rights

```
includelib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64\msvcmrt.lib"
includelib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.20348.0\um\x64\kernel32.lib"
includelib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64\vcruntime.lib"
includelib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.20348.0\ucrt\x64\ucrt.lib"
    
ExitProcess PROTO
CreateFileA PROTO
CreateDirectoryA PROTO
WriteFile PROTO

clearRegisters MACRO
    XOR RAX, RAX
    XOR RDX, RDX
    XOR RCX, RCX
    XOR R8, R8
    XOR R9, R9
ENDM

GENERIC_WRITE    EQU 40000000h
FILE_SHARE_READ  EQU 1
FILE_SHARE_WRITE EQU 2
OPEN_ALWAYS      EQU 4
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL EQU 128

.DATA
    pathName byte "D:\thanks",0
    fileName byte "D:\thanks\ASSEMBLY.txt", 0
    fileHandle QWORD ?
    txt BYTE "Learning Assembly for shellcode development.", 0
    num DWORD ?

.CODE
main PROC
    sub RSP, 56
    
    clearRegisters
    
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
; Create Directory
    
    LEA RCX,pathName
    MOV RDX,0
    
    CALL CreateDirectoryA
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
; Create File   
    
    LEA RCX, fileName
    MOV RDX, GENERIC_WRITE
    MOV R8, FILE_SHARE_READ OR FILE_SHARE_WRITE
    MOV R9, 0

    MOV QWORD PTR [RSP+32], OPEN_ALWAYS
    MOV QWORD PTR [RSP+40], FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
    MOV QWORD PTR [RSP+48], 0

    CALL CreateFileA
    MOV fileHandle, RAX

    clearRegisters
    
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
; Write to the File     

    MOV RCX, fileHandle
    LEA RDX, txt
    MOV R8, LENGTHOF txt
    LEA R9, num
    MOV QWORD PTR [RSP+32],  0

    CALL WriteFile
    TEST RAX, RAX

    CALL ExitProcess
main ENDP

END
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful response! It solved my issue.